# Oracle to Aurora - DMS - Failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, import, dms

Need a Suggestion on the below. I was trying to do a DMS to aurora and i have installed python3.8.8. I have installed all required modules. Openssl is also installed.

When i trigger the script i encounter the below error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "task_runner.py", line 2, in
>
> import boto3   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/**init**.py", line 16,
> in 
> from boto3.session import Session   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 17, in
>
> import botocore.session   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 30,
> in 
> import botocore.credentials   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line
> 34, in 
> from botocore.config import Config   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/config.py", line 16,
> in 
> from botocore.endpoint import DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, MAX_POOL_CONNECTIONS   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line
> 22, in 
> from botocore.awsrequest import create_request_object   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line
> 26, in 
> import botocore.utils   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 33,
> in 
> import botocore.httpsession   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line
> 8, in 
> from urllib3.util.ssl_ import ( ImportError: cannot import name 'ssl' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_'
> (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py)

I have tried changing the version of python as suggested in another post and also reinstalled awscli but nothing works. no matter what version of python used, i always end up with the same error.

Lastly, the server where am doing this doesnt have an internet connection.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: This is a traceback without an exception message and associated code, what do you expect us to do?

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'ssl' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py)  -  this is the error message

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning up the entire Python setup and editing the Setup.dist to use SSL during build resolved the issue.